# Can i change the side navigation automatically?

Tags: document-library, navigation, global-navigation, current-navigation, html-form-web-part

Our users are creating new pages and sub-sites.  Our users want to manage their own page's sidebar menu. They want to add new pages on to the menu and delete old pages from menu

Users can edit lists because they have the Manage Heirarchy permission level defined for them.   Can I fetch the sidebar menu from a list? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about the user's permissions, that they only have edit?

Since this [MS link on permissions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/sites/user-permissions-and-permission-levels) shows that either **Design** or **Manage Heirarchy** are needed.

The above link says it applies to: "*SharePoint 2013 and SharePoint Server 2016*".

**Update**

Your users should be able to use 'edit links' according to this [MS article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/customize-the-navigation-on-your-sharepoint-site-3cd61ae7-a9ed-4e1e-bf6d-4655f0bf25ca#ID0EAACAAA=2013,_2016).

[image: Edit Links screen shot]

Comment: sorry i said wrong. I mean Manage Heirarchy.

Comment: Are the users able to access  the Site Settings menu to select Navigation?

Comment: No we dont want them to use Navigation. Because they can make  chaos. It should be more easier.

Comment: I've posted a picture in my answer to explain what I mean